# Unable to successfully send the [ctrl][p] keys to a non-angular page

Tags: angular, google-chrome, typescript, protractor

Using protractor version 5.1.2
,Angular 5
,typescript 2.4.2

I'm unable to trigger a 'print' using the shortcut keys '[ctrl][p]' with protractor on a non angular page.In my protractor script i switch from an angular page to a non angular page in a new tab; I am able to locate the 'embed' tag in the HTML of this page but when i try to send the keys [ctrl][p] nothing happens. Here is the statement i am using:

browser.driver.actions().sendKeys(Key.CONTROL,'p',Key.NULL)

The above statement uses the syntax which is referenced in the protractor API reference so it should work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is a snippet of the script

```
await browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(async function (handles) {
        if(handles.length = 1){
           await browser.sleep(2000)
        } 
       })
await browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(async function (handles) {
        let reporthandle = handles[1];

await browser.switchTo().window(reporthandle).then( function(){

         browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
         browser.driver.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.CONTROL, 'p')
```

Comment: Can you post an example code?

Comment: 1) `actions()` need to be completed with `perform()`.  2) Maybe try `keyDown` instead of `sendKeys`.  3) please dont post images of code, just add it to the question

Comment: @Gunderson. Thanks for your suggestions. I tried the perform() and keyDown but still does not work.

Answer (score 1):

1. `browser.ignoreSynchronization` is deprecated. Use in protractor config instead:

   ```
   onPrepare() {
     browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false)
   }
   ```
2. Why do you use `browser.driver.actions()` instead of `browser.actions()`? Try it